# Number of Page Faults?

Tags: operating-system

Here is the problem:

A program whose size is 460 bytes will access a series of addresses: `10,11,104,170,73,309,185,245,246,434 and 364`. 
The page size is `100` bytes and the program only uses 200 bytes in main memory. 
If the OS use FIFO algorithm, how many page fault interrupts will occur? Why?

Comment: If you want people to help with your homework, you're well advised to show that you've made some kind of attempt at it. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info

Comment: @AdamWright I have done, I want to know am i right. I am not sure.

Comment: @AdamWright Oh no, when i post my problem, after that i was editing my answer about it and the format.  I don't know how to show a table.

Comment: My heart was hurt. Anyway I ate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think   may be like this.
address   | current Memory |  status
 10           0-100            page fault

11           0-100

104          0-100|100-200    page fault

170          0-100|100-200

73           0-100|100-200

309          100-200|300-400  page fault

185          100-200|300-400

245          300-400|200-300 page fault

246          300-400|200-300 page fault

434          200-300|400-500 page fault

364          400-500|300-400 page fault

Am I right?  I notice this program is 460 byte. And page alignment is 100byte.